# How can I make my view controller setted as it's own delegate?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 'helper' singleton class that needs to pop up a login, if a login is required. I want to capture the return from the login view controller, so I have implemented a protocol in my LoginViewController, and need to set my delegate in the singleton class, but when I attempt to do:

```
loginController.delegate = self
```

Xcode tries to correct it as:

```
loginController.delegate = self as! LoginViewControllerDelegate
```

The protocol in my LoginViewController.swift file:

```
protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate {
    func loginViewControllerDidReturn(identifier: String)
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your LoginViewController definition is :

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, LoginViewControllerDelegate {
...
}
```

This inform the compiler that your class implement the protocol.

You can also make an extension implementing the protocol :

```
extension LoginViewController: LoginViewControllerDelegate {
    // Implement here the func of your protocol
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem. How/where should I implement my protocols? I've been adding them to the tops of my view controller .swift files. Is this not the right place?

Comment: You can do it wherever you want. For a delegate, I generally do the same as you : at the top of the class that it is the delegate of

Comment: But this is not a singleton pattern design you're dealing with, it a delegation. I will edit your title that is not relevant

Answer (score 1):

Does 'self' conform to the LoginViewControllerDelegate protocol?